# main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php on line 43

Tags: magento2

[image]I upgraded (luckily) my testserver to 2.3.4 (from 2.3.3) and i can't view the full order information anymore. Also mail is not send when i want to send an invoice.

Strange thing is that i also upgraded an other server with almost the same configuration and there is no problem...

**system.log:**

```
main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php on line 43
```

**exception.log**

```
main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php on line 43 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/IfDirective.php on line 43 at vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

[image]

Comment: What about Orders after upgrading, can you fully see them ?

Comment: Before upgrading (2.3.3) the adress and account information were fine, after upgrading (2.3.4) they dissapeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.

After removing the rows in database table "directory_country_format" it works fine again. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Yes! This did the trick, strange that this table pops-up suddenly

Answer (score 4):

Neither the first nor the second solution worked for me.

My database table "directory_country_format" was empty and after deleting some if statements in two email templates the error still occured.

But - I made a database dump and found "{{if" statements in:

- customer/address_templates/text'
- customer/address_templates/oneline
- customer/address_templates/pdf

These can be found in Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates.

I took these templates from a fresh Magento 2 installation:

**Text:**

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
{{var country}}
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

**Text Oneline:**

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}, {{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}
```

**PDF:**

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}|{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}}, {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}|{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
```

And with these templates the error is gone! AND I had a second problem - no order emails were sent - this problem is also gone!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there's an if directive somewhere (in your e-mail template or such) and it's using a variable which isn't accessible ([anymore?](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html)).

if directive:

```
{if var}text{/if}
```

Comment: Is my email template (or extension) influencing the display of an order in the admin view? I already switched out my email extension and that didn't improve, maybe i have some modifications in my theme that are regarding to email. Any idea in wich folder/file i have to wach?

Comment: One would expect that the if directive and the order info issue are 2 separate things. Are order e-mails getting sent after disabling your e-mail extension? The email templates can be found in `email/` directories and stored in email_template. If e-mails are getting sent, there should be an other reason/error which breaks the order view.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was a missing `{{/depend}}` statement in one of the transaction emails. I narrowed it down by previewing every template. If there is a missing statement, then the preview won't show.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. In my case it was caused by a missing `{{/if}}` in the HTML customer address template. This template worked under Magento 1.9.2 but after migration it caused the issue in Magento 2.3.3.